# Get opposite of number if middle is not zero

Tags: ios4

I need a function that will return the opposite of a number, but i also need to be able to specify the 'center'.

eg. Center = 0.
If the number was 10, it would return -10.

I need this:
Center = 100.
If the number was 10, it would return 190.

Any idea how it could be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this just subtraction and addition?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(int) returnOppositeOf:(int)myNumber aroundCenter:(int)center
{

return ( (center*2) - myNumber);

}
```

Comment: And yet, not the accepted answer. Perhaps the OP actually needed this for math class, rather than iPhone dev?

Answer (score 2):

Opposite = 2 * Center - X

Comment: I'm so conflicted as to which to give my vote, Jim clearly wins on time, but can I forgive him for the double negative?

Comment: The suspense is *figuratively* killing me! :)

Comment: @Jean: Well, my way is less susceptible to intermediate results overflowing, but I'd be a liar if I claimed to have been thinking about that as I was writing it!

Answer (score 1):

opp = center - (x - center)